# docker start a container after stopping

Tags: docker

I built a phalcon php image with this Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER betojulio

COPY apache2_evogas.conf /tmp/apache2.conf

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apache2 \
    php5-dev \
    php5-mysql \
    libapache2-mod-php5 \
    gcc \
    libpcre3-dev \
    git \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && git clone git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git \
    && cd cphalcon/build \
    && ./install \
    && cd /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d \
    && echo 'extension=phalcon.so' > phalcon_php.ini \
    && cp /tmp/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf \
    && a2enmod rewrite

CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

and I create the container running this command line

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver -v /www:/var/www/html  betojulio/phalcon_project:1.0
```

and everything works well.

My question is, after I stop the container how do I restart the same container 'webserver' with the same options '-d -p 80:80 -v /www:/var/www/html' or after stopping the container I have to delete it and create it again?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: docker start webserver

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like the other answer said, to start a stopped container, you run:

`docker start <container name or id>`

If it doesn't stay running, check the logs:

`docker logs <container name or id>`

If you want the container to restart automatically if it stops for some reason look at [docker restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart).

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 80:80 --name webserver -v /www:/var/www/html  betojulio/phalcon_project:1.0
```

Also, you might want to change your CMD to the following in your Dockerfile.

```
CMD ["apache2", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: docker logs webserver returns " AH00558: apache2: Could not reliaby determine the server's fully qualifed domain name, using 127.17.0.3. Set the 'Servername directive globaly to supress this message' Httpd (pid 9 already running)"

Comment: You will need to change the server name in the apache2.conf config file.

Comment: I changed config file! still not not working 
I have in docker logs webservice httpd (9) already running

Answer (score 1):

```
docker start webserver
```

That's it.

Comment: I have try " docker start webserver " but the container does not stay running

I type "docker ps -a" and on the status field I have Exited (0) 2 seconds ago

Comment: Sounds like your process is stopping again. Anything useful in the logs (`docker logs webserver`)?

Comment: docker logs webserver returns " AH00558: apache2: Could not reliaby determine the server's fully qualifed domain name, using 127.17.0.3. Set the 'Servername directive globaly to supress this message' Httpd (pid 9 already running)"

Answer (score 0):

I have some feedback.

When I run my image with

`docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver -v /www:/var/www/html  betojulio/phalcon_project:1.0`

the first time everything works well.

The command running in the container is **"/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin"**. I know this typing 'docker ps'.
I can not restart the container because the command that is running.

If I remove 'CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND' from the Dockerfile ,build an image and run the container with

`docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver -v /www:/var/www/html  betojulio/phalcon_project:1.0 /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND`

The command running in the container is **/usr/sbin/apache2ctl** and after stopping the container I can start it with 'docker start container'

Is this normal or there is a bug?

Comment: Change your CMD in the dockerfile to 'CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"] and see if that helps.

Comment: ok this is my new CMD line "CMD ['/usr/sbin/apache2ctl', '-D', 'FOREGROUND'] ".
After building the image, I run ' docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver -v /www:/var/www/html  betojulio/phalcon_project:1.0 '
Container does not stay running, docker logs returns '/bin/sh:1:[/usr/sbin/apache2ctl,-D,FOREGROUND]: not found '

Comment: Hmm odd, not sure if it would matter, but did you try double quotes " instead of single quotes ' ?

Comment: This seems to work for others: https://github.com/paulczar/docker-apache2/blob/master/Dockerfile#L22 but they are using apache2 instead of apache2ctl

Comment: I just tried with double quotes . I can run the image for the first time. when I stop it I can not restart it . Docker logs returns 'httpd (pid 8) already running'

Comment: Did you try with apache2 instead of apache2ctl?

Comment: @ Ken Cochrane, thank you for your help !

I tried with apache2 and It is working

If you want to write an answer I will accept it

Comment: You're welcome, I have an answer already, if you want to accept that one.